# in drupal 7, how to get node id from url in the view?

Tags: drupal, url, view

I want to add a comment form to my view by adding

$node->nid), 'comment'); 
?>

however, it shows up a error saying undefined variable $node->nid, then I realize it is a view not a content type

In the view, by choosing the right url, for example, /projects/{username}/{nodeid}, I only show one content.

so I guess I can get the node id by parsing the 3rd argument of the url, so question might be how to get node id from url in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On views page /projects/{username}/{nodeid} `<?php print arg(2);?>` will give you node id.

Meany nodes can have the same title, you need to use another way, for examlple  /projects/{username}/{nodeurl}. But i can't understand why you use views to display single node? For each node you can create specific patern (just like /projects/{username}/{nodetitle}) for url with module http://drupal.org/project/pathauto then costomize output of the node including comments form and other parts.

Comment: Thanks, through arg(2) I can get the id, and another question is I have another view arg(2) points to a node title, how can I query the node id through node title?   I used this for example,                                   $title = arg(2);
    $node = node_load(array('title' => $title));    
    $nid = $node->nid;
    print $nid;                                                         but a error shows up saying  that an only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() ,  I don't know whether this way is correct or not